# Subsetting in a function to calculate a row total

Tags: function, r, sum, subset

I have a data frame with results for certain instruments, and I want to create a new column which contains the totals of each row. Because I have different numbers of instruments each time I run an analysis on new data, I need a function to dynamically calculate the new column with the Row Total.

To simply my problem, here’s what my data frame looks like:

```
    Type    Value
1   A   10
2   A   15
3   A   20
4   A   25
5   B   30
6   B   40
7   B   50
8   B   60
9   B   70
10  B   80
11  B   90
```

My goal is to achieve the following:

```
    A   B   Total
1   10  30  40
2   15  40  55
3   20  50  70
4   25  60  85
5       70  70
6       80  80
7       90  90
```

I’ve tried various method, but this way holds the most promise:

```
myList <- list(a = c(10, 15, 20, 25), b = c(30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90))
tmpDF <- data.frame(sapply(myList, '[', 1:max(sapply(myList, length))))
> tmpDF
   a  b
1 10 30
2 15 40
3 20 50
4 25 60
5 NA 70
6 NA 80
7 NA 90
totalSum <- rowSums(tmpDF)
totalSum <- data.frame(totalSum)
tmpDF <- cbind(tmpDF, totalSum)
> tmpDF
   a  b totalSum
1 10 30       40
2 15 40       55
3 20 50       70
4 25 60       85
5 NA 70       NA
6 NA 80       NA
7 NA 90       NA
```

Even though this way did succeeded in combining two data frames of different lengths, the ‘rowSums’ function gives the wrong values in this example. Besides that, my original data isn't in a list format, so I can't apply such a 'solution'.

I think I’m overcomplicating this problem, so I was wondering how can I …

- Subset data from a data frame on the basis of ‘Type’,
- Insert these individual subsets of different lengths into a new data frame,
- Add an ‘Total’ column to this data frame which is the correct sum of the
  individual subsets.

An added complication to this problem is that this needs to be done in an function or in an otherwise dynamic way, so that I don’t need to manually subset the dozens of ‘Types’ (A, B, C, and so on) in my data frame.

Here’s what I have so far, which doesn’t work, but illustrates the lines I’m thinking along:

```
TotalDf <- function(x){
    tmpNumberOfTypes <- c(levels(x$Type))
    for( i in tmpNumberOfTypes){
        subSetofData <- subset(x, Type = i, select = Value)
        if( i == 1) {
        totalDf <- subSetOfData }
        else{
        totalDf <- cbind(totalDf, subSetofData)}
    }
    return(totalDf)
}
```

Thanks in advance for any thoughts or ideas on this,

Regards,

```
EDIT:
```

Thanks to the comment of Joris (see below) I got an end in the right direction, however, when trying to translate his solution to my data frame, I run into additional problems. His proposed answer works, and gives me the following (correct) sum of the values of A and B:

```
> tmp78 <- tapply(DF$value,DF$id,sum)
> tmp78
 1  2  3  4  5  6 
 6  8 10 12  9 10 
> data.frame(tmp78)
  tmp78
1     6
2     8
3    10
4    12
5     9
6    10
```

However, when I try this solution on my data frame, it doesn’t work:

```
> subSetOfData <- copyOfTradesList[c(1:3,11:13),c(1,10)]
> subSetOfData
   Instrument AccountValue
1         JPM         6997
2         JPM         7261
3         JPM         7545
11        KFT         6992
12        KFT         6944
13        KFT         7069
> unlist(sapply(rle(subSetOfData$Instrument)$lengths,function(x) 1:x))
Error in rle(subSetOfData$Instrument) : 'x' must be an atomic vector
> subSetOfData$InstrumentNumeric <- as.numeric(subSetOfData$Instrument)
> unlist(sapply(rle(subSetOfData$InstrumentNumeric)$lengths,function(x) 1:x))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    3    3
> subSetOfData$id <- unlist(sapply(rle(subSetOfData$InstrumentNumeric)$lengths,function(x) 1:x))
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "id", value = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L,  : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 6
```

I have the disturbing idea that I’m going around in circles…

Comment: You figured out yourself rls doesn't work on factors. But there's something odd. I can't reproduce your error, it works fine for me. Did you update to R 2.12.1? In any case, if you get internal errors installing plyr, it would be wise to spend 2 minutes to reinstall R. It really doesn't take longer than that.

Comment: @Joris: I didn't yet updated to the newest version, as I'm always a little hesitant with those things (2 minutes sounds encouraging enough to warrant an update. :) ). Have you trouble reproducing the 'plyr error' or the error from the 'unlist' function? I truly hope the former, otherwise it suggests that there a differences in the standard functions of R with version 2.12.1 contra 2.11.

Comment: I can't reproduce either of them, but I was referring to the unlist function. I can confirm that 2.12 indeed works a bit different than 2.11, but all changes I found were for the better. 2.12.1 is running smoothly and bugfree for all I know. Updating is definitely a good choice.

Comment: @Joris: I've updated R and still experience the unlist error (which doesn't matter because with lapply I'm still able to calculate the totals). The library reshape does work now. :) So thanks for your encouragement, even tough I didn't hit the target of two minutes. ;) haha

Comment: Yeah, as pchalasani said. sapply only works when the number of cases in each level aren't the same. I missed that one, sorry. So lapply is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two thoughts :

1) you could use na.rm=T in rowSums

2) How do you know which one has to go with which? You might add some indexing.

eg :

```
DF <- data.frame(
  type=c(rep("A",4),rep("B",6)),
  value = 1:10,
  stringsAsFactors=F
)


DF$id <- unlist(lapply(rle(DF$type)$lengths,function(x) 1:x))
```

Now this allows you to easily `tapply` the sum on the original dataframe

```
tapply(DF$value,DF$id,sum)
```

And, more importantly, get your dataframe in the correct form :

```
> DF
   type value id
1     A     1  1
2     A     2  2
3     A     3  3
4     A     4  4
5     B     5  1
6     B     6  2
7     B     7  3
8     B     8  4
9     B     9  5
10    B    10  6

> library(reshape)
> cast(DF,id~type)
  id  A  B
1  1  1  5
2  2  2  6
3  3  3  7
4  4  4  8
5  5 NA  9
6  6 NA 10
```

Comment: Thanks Joris, suggestion 1 solves the NA problem in the total row. Good point your second suggestion. Matching (for example on time) is something for further analysis, and I didn't want to make the question to long. However, they are already matched in the sense that the first Value of A happened roughly in the same time period as the first Value of B.

Comment: @Jura : then you can add some id. I adapted my answer with an example, allowing for a simple cast.

Comment: @Joris: Thanks for your further elaboration, however I get an error when entering "DF$Total <- tapply(DF$value,DF$id,sum)" which says: "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Total", value = c(6L, 8L, 10L, 12L,  :  replacement has 6 rows, data has 10" or is this something to be expected and dependent on the reshape package? I'm asking because I can't install the plyr package (on which reshape depends) (R gives an internal error), and I would rather not remove and reinstall R to try to solve this 'plyr error' unless it is absolutely needed for my question. (Sorry to bother you again)

Comment: @Joris: I've updated my question after I got your tapply sum working in the example. However, when adopted to my dataframe I run into the same troubles. (I've updated my question with more information).

Comment: @Jura25: use `lapply` in place of `sapply` and it should work. `sapply` tries to be helpful my putting the results into a matrix form when possible -- in our case the number of `JPM` and `KFT` are the same, so the `sapply` puts the results in a matrix form, and you end up assigning a matrix to the `id` column of the data-frame, which will produce strange results. However `lapply` does not do this, so the `unlist` will do the intended 'flattening' of the result into a vector.

Comment: @Jura : sorry, wrongly copied the code, corrected it now. Off course you can't tapply the thing like it is. And after the recast or your own remodeling, a simple `rowSums(...,na.rm=T)` works perfectly well.

Comment: @pchalasani: Thanks! That did the trick. Combined with the example from @Joris (thanks for correction/new comment) it works like a charm now. :) Thanks again you both!

Answer (score 0):

```
TV <- data.frame(Type = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
             , Value = c(10,15,20,25,30,40,50,60,70,80,90)
             , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Added Type C for testing
# TV <- data.frame(Type = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B", "C", "C", "C")
#                  , Value = c(10,15,20,25,30,40,50,60,70,80,90, 100, 150, 130)
#                  , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

lnType <- with(TV, tapply(Value, Type, length))
lnType <- as.integer(lnType)
lnType

id <- unlist(mapply(FUN = rep_len, length.out = lnType, x = list(1:max(lnType))))
(TV <- cbind(id, TV))

require(reshape2)
tvWide <- dcast(TV, id ~ Type)

# Alternatively
# tvWide <- reshape(data = TV,  direction = "wide", timevar = "Type",  ids = c(id, Type))

tvWide <- subset(tvWide, select = -id)

# If you want something neat without the <NA>
# for(i in 1:ncol(tvWide)){
#
#     if (is.na(tvWide[j,i])){
#       tvWide[j,i] = 0
#     }
#     
#   }
# }

tvWide
transform(tvWide, rowSum=rowSums(tvWide, na.rm = TRUE))
```